# how do I style the words of a string if and only if they are present in an array , other words are kept normal in react-native

Tags: javascript, android, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I am setting up a new screen like the editor of C.I wanted to highlight the pre-defined words and special symbols like { , [ , ( , < , > , ; , : , ' , " by putting all of them in an array .

Here is the Code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View,Text} from 'react-native';

class highlight extends Component{
 render(){
  return(
   <Text>{this.props.children}</Text>
  );
 }
}
class programs1 extends Component{
   render()
      return(
      <View>
           <Text>printf<highlight >("</highlight>short int is %2d bytes 
                      \\n<highlight>",</highlight> sizeof<highlight> 
                      (</highlight>short int<highlight>));</highlight>
               </Text>
          </View>
          );
       }
    }
    export default programs1 ;
```

this is working but,it is not a good idea to include a defined tag every time.it becomes a tedious task to include a defined tag every time . so,i wanted to put all the c program content in a string "C_Content" and key words in an array "Key_Words". whenever we find an element of an array "Key_Words" in the string "C_Content" we need to highlight that. but I don't know how to implement that .

`const C_Content=printf("   short int is %2d bytes \\n", sizeof(int));`

`const  Key_Words=['%' , '&' , '*' , '(' , ')' , '{' , '}' , '[' , ']' , ':' , ';' ]`

in the output all the words of string "C_Content" must be highlighted if they are belongs to the array "key_Words" must be highlighted.